# How to install package dependencies for a custom Airbyte connector?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a custom connector for Airbyte, and it involves extracting files from different compressed formats, like `.zip` or `.7z`. My plan was to use [patool](http://wummel.github.io/patool/) for this, and indeed it works in local tests, running:

```bash
python main.py read --config valid_config.json --catalog configured_catalog_old.json
```

However, since Airbyte runs in docker containers, I need those containers to have packages like `p7zip` installed. So my question is, what is the proper way to do that?

I just downloaded and deployed Airbyte Open Source in my own machine using the recommended commands listed on [Airbyte documentation](https://docs.airbyte.com/quickstart/deploy-airbyte):

```bash
git clone https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte.git
cd airbyte
docker compose up
```

I tried using `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` into `airbyte/worker` and `airbyte/connector-builder-server`, to install `p7zip` directly, but it's not working yet. My connector calls patoolib from a Python script, but it is unable to process the given file, because it fails to find a program to extract it. This is the log output:

```
> patool: Extracting /tmp/tmpan2mjkmn ...
> unknown archive format for file `/tmp/tmpan2mjkmn'
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I completely ignored that the connector template comes with a `Dockerfile`, which is used precisely to configure the container that is supposed to run the connector code. So all I had to do was to add this line do `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y file p7zip p7zip-full lzma lzma-dev
```

Specifically, to use `patoolib`, I had to install the `file` package, so it could detect the mime type of archive files.